# How to insert a buffer that is a char pointer into Mongodb using C++?

Tags: c++, json, mongodb

I have a buffer i.e a char pointer which has some jSON data itself ,so I want to insert this data into  Mongodb.

My approach is,

```
           char *buff=NULL;
           {buff has some JSON data}

           mongo::BSONObj *obj_data= new mongo::BSONObj(buff) ;
           conn.insert( "mydb.testcollect",obj_data,0);
```

I am getting this message,

error: no matching function for call to ‘mongo::DBClientConnection::insert(const char [17], mongo::BSONObj*&, int)’

What will be the right approach .plz help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the latest version of the legacy driver, you should include [db/json.h](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/legacy-1.1.2/src/mongo/db/json.h), and then write the following:

```
try {
    mongo::BSONObj obj = mongo::fromjson(buff);
}
catch (const mongo::MsgAssertionException& exception) {
    // Handle parsing failure.
}
conn.insert("mydb.testcollect", obj);
std::string error = conn.getLastError();
if (!error.empty()) {
    // Handle remote error.
}
```

If you're starting a new project, then strongly consider using the mongocxx driver (versions 3.0.x and greater of C++ driver series) instead of the legacy driver.  The improved API of mongocxx will make writing C++ client code for MongoDB much more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
       mongo::BSONObj obj_data(buff) ;
       conn.insert( "mydb.testcollect", obj_data,0);
```

By the way, you are using outdated driver version. Consider switching to latest one.

Comment: yes now am not getting error at compile time,but at run time am getting this error,"errorThu Sep 29 15:13:23 Assertion: 10334:Invalid BSONObj size: 1919230587

Comment: @RinkuBuragohain well that is next question. I am not sure you can just feed JSON string to BSONObj constructor. You should check documentation but it is rather vague "Construct a BSONObj from data in the proper format.": http://api.mongodb.com/cxx-26compat/legacy-0.0-26compat-2.6.0-rc0/classmongo_1_1_b_s_o_n_obj.html#a62439b4322fed88fde356de9a77d8ebe

Comment: @RinkuBuragohain I would suggest to switching to latest version of driver, it has better structure and docs